# Custom Fonts load in IE10 then revert back to browser default font

Tags: asp-classic, fonts, internet-explorer-10, revert

has anyone ever experienced a Font that would load OK, then revert back to a default font after the page reloaded?
In ASP.net I use custom fonts from Font Squirrel that loads OK, but after a reload of the page the customer font reverts back to default font.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Any demo code would be appreciated.